# Python: Return max float instead of infs?

Tags: python, floating-point

I have several functions with multiple calculations that might return `inf`, like so:

```
In [10]: numpy.exp(5000)
Out[10]: inf
```

I'd rather it return the maximum float value:

```
In [11]: sys.float_info.max
Out[11]: 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

I could put in checks for every time an `inf` might pop up, or wrap each calculation in a function that rounds `inf` down to the desired float. However, I'd really like a simple hack at the beginning of every function, like:

```
inf = sys.float_info.max
```

Which obviously doesn't work. Is there a smart way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: I think this is just asking for numerical problems. Where are you going with this?

Comment: aix, you're right. The issue was due to `inf/inf` producing `nan`, instead of `1`, which was a problem. I've now rearranged those particular calculations so such blowups won't happen, thus removing my need for the `inf` hack. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [decorator](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-decorator):

```
import sys
def noInf(f):
  def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
    res = f(*args, **kwargs)
    if res == float('inf'):
      return sys.float_info.max
    return res
  return wrapped

@noInf
def myMult(x, y):
  return x*y

print(myMult(sys.float_info.max, 2)) # prints 1.79769313486e+308
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about 'replacing' infinity value, but what about using `min()`?
Something like (assuming `x` yields your value):

```
return min ( [ x, sys.float_info.max ] )
```